# Force TabController to create all tabs Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a default page with two tabs, using TabBar and TabController. All is working fine, except when I enter the page, the second tab's build method is only called when I click to change to the second tab. The problem is that when I enter the page I want both tabs to be already created (a.k.a their build methods executed). Any thoughts?

Illustration code:

```
//This widget is used inside a Scaffold
class TabsPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new TabsPageState();

}

class TabsPageState extends State<TabsPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  List<Tab> _tabs;
  List<Widget> _pages;
  TabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabs = [
      new Tab(text: 'TabOne'),
      new Tab(text: 'TabTwo')
    ];
    _pages = [
      //Just normal stateful widgets
      new TabOne(),
      new TabTwo()
    ];
    _controller = new TabController(length: _tabs.length, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new TabBar(
            controller: _controller,
            tabs: _tabs
          ),
          new SizedBox.fromSize(
            size: const Size.fromHeight(540.0),
            child: new TabBarView(
                controller: _controller,
                children: _pages
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a Form with fields in both Tabs, When I first enter the page and submite the form, I need to validate and make shure all fields are filled. And because the second Tab content wasn't generated, those fields are ignored and may stay empty.

Comment: Are you using flutter form (https://flutter.io/cookbook/forms/validation/)?

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian yes, I am.

Comment: How are you able to use one form for both the tabs?

Comment: The Form's child is a statefulWidget that controls both Tabs (basically the code above). Just like that

Comment: @JonahWilliams any suggestions?

Comment: hey @JulioHenriqueBitencourt have you managed to solve the problem? I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this.

In my case, I had 2 tabs and I wanted to preload the other tab.

So what I did was, I initialised the tab controller in `initState` like this:

```
tabController = TabController(
  length: 2,
  vsync: this,
  initialIndex: 1,
);
```

I set the `initialIndex` to the other tabs index, and then set the index back in after the build was done like this:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  tabController.index = 0;
});
```

But this may only work if you have 2 tabs

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I'm using Tabs with Forms and I wanted to validate all of them, my solution was to switch to the second tab programmatically, It doesn't make sense to not visit a tab with a form that requires validation.

So given a global key for each form:

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

The reason I wanted all tabs to be built was to use:

```
_formKey.currentState.validate()
```

So my fix is

```
if (_formKey.currentState == null) { //The tab was never visited, force it
  _tabController.animateTo(1);
  return;
}
```